# Arranging widgets in ipywidgets interactive

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, interactive, ipywidgets

I have this interactive graph code using ipywidgets; but not sure how to arragne the each variable inside the interactive function in widgets. the default layout is vertical. But I want to arrange them in horizontal way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('seaborn')
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
from ipywidgets import interactive,interact
#function to plot the different curves
def plot_function(u=1,v=2,w=3,x=4,y=5,z=6):
    time=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    df=pd.DataFrame({"Y1":np.sin(time*u*2*np.pi),"y2":np.sin(time*v*2*np.pi),"y3":np.sin(time*w*2*np.pi),
                    "y4":np.sin(time*x*2*np.pi),"y5":np.sin(time*y*2*np.pi),"y6":np.sin(time*z*2*np.pi)})
    df.plot()
widget=interactive(plot_function,u=1,v=2,w=3,x=4,y=5,z=6)
widget
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`interactive` is restricted to fairly simple widget layouts. Have a look at the [Flexbox](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-Flexbox-layout) options if you want to customize them some more.

One simple get around is to use the `interactive` call to generate and link your widgets and functions, then restructure the widgets inside a HBox. Then add a layout that tells the box to wrap at line ends. I added a couple more imports and three lines at the end to achieve this.

1) `controls` - an `HBox` of your input widgets.

2) The `Output` widget generated by the `interactive` call.

3) A `VBox` that wraps the two together.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('seaborn')
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
#importing the necessary items from the Ipywidgets library 
from ipywidgets import interactive,interact, HBox, Layout,VBox
#function to plot the different curves
def plot_function(u=1,v=2,w=3,x=4,y=5,z=6):
    time=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    df=pd.DataFrame({"Y1":np.sin(time*u*2*np.pi),"y2":np.sin(time*v*2*np.pi),"y3":np.sin(time*w*2*np.pi),
                    "y4":np.sin(time*x*2*np.pi),"y5":np.sin(time*y*2*np.pi),"y6":np.sin(time*z*2*np.pi)})
    df.plot()
widget=interactive(plot_function,u=1,v=2,w=3,x=4,y=5,z=6)
controls = HBox(widget.children[:-1], layout = Layout(flex_flow='row wrap'))
output = widget.children[-1]
display(VBox([controls, output]))
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, if you're happy with the answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick to the left.

Comment: Is it possible to have plot_function be called on execution of this cell, rather than after the first manipulation of a widget?

Comment: Don't think so, normally doing `display(widget)` will run the function once, but using the vBox approach means the function won't get run.

Comment: You can do widget.update() to get the output displayed

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is the decorator which I am using instead of @interact:

```py
def interact_delayed(_InteractFactory__interact_f=None, **kwargs):
    def patch(obj):
        if hasattr(obj.widget, 'layout'):
            obj.widget.layout = Layout(flex_flow='row wrap')
        for child in obj.widget.children:
            if hasattr(child, 'continuous_update'):
                child.continuous_update = False
        return obj
    if _InteractFactory__interact_f is None:
        def decorator(f):
            obj = interact(f, **kwargs)
            return patch(obj)
        return decorator
    else:
        obj = interact(_InteractFactory__interact_f, **kwargs)
        return patch(obj)
```

The `patch` function modifies default attributes of ipywidget object: applies the Layout suggested in the previous answer and also sets `continuous_update` to false which I found useful in my cases.
The if-else branches takes care about decorator versus function use-case scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use widgets.interactive_output and grid

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# plt.style.use('seaborn')
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
from ipywidgets import interactive_output
#function to plot the different curves

u_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=10, step=1, description='u')
v_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=2, min=0, max=10, step=1, description='v')
w_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=3, min=0, max=10, step=1, description='w')
x_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=4, min=0, max=10, step=1, description='x')
y_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=5, min=0, max=10, step=1, description='y')
z_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=6, min=0, max=10, step=1, description='z')
grid = GridspecLayout(2, 3, height='300px', width = '1200px')
grid[0,0] = u_slider
grid[0,1] = v_slider
grid[0,2] = w_slider
grid[1,0] = x_slider
grid[1,1] = y_slider
grid[1,2] = z_slider

def plot_function(u,v,w,x,y,z):
    time=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    df=pd.DataFrame({"Y1":np.sin(time*u*2*np.pi),"y2":np.sin(time*v*2*np.pi),"y3":np.sin(time*w*2*np.pi),
                    "y4":np.sin(time*x*2*np.pi),"y5":np.sin(time*y*2*np.pi),"y6":np.sin(time*z*2*np.pi)})
    df.plot()
widget=interactive_output(plot_function,{'u':u_slider,'v':v_slider,'w':w_slider,
                                         'x':x_slider, 'y':y_slider,'z':z_slider})

display(grid,widget)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to arrange widgets by adding a parameter in "interact" or interactive.