# How to add independent titles or headers to dropdown menus created using ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using the following code to produce a tool in a Jupyter Notebook that allows the user to print a statement describing which coloured fruit they would like to try:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive

fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple','Lemon','Orange']
colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow']

drop1 = widgets.Dropdown(options=fruits, value='Banana', description='Fruit:', disabled=False)
drop2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=colors, value='Blue', description='Color:', disabled=False)


def update_dropdown(fruit, color):
    info = f"I would love to try a {color.lower()} {fruit.lower()}!"
    display(info)  

w = interactive(update_dropdown, fruit=drop1, color=drop2) 
display(w)
```

The code comes from the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828993/how-to-build-multiple-dropdown-prompt-function-using-ipywidget/74829153?noredirect=1#comment132104540_74829153).

When the user chooses a fruit and/or a color from the dropdown menus, an associated print statement should also be printed, reading "I would love to try a {color} {fruit}!". The following image, produced by the code above, show how the partial, expected output looks like in Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

However, I am trying to display "Choose a fruit!" right above the fruit dropdown menu and display "Choose a color right above the color dropdown menu, as so:
[image]

When I try to insert these print statements using the following code:

```
...
drop1 = ...
print("Hey")

drop2 = ...
print("Hello")
```

I see this, which is not what I want:

[image]

How can I modify the `.interactive()` function line to insert the print statements I am trying to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get some idea of how to solve this problem from the last example of [The Grid Layout](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Layout.html#The-Grid-layout) section: see output of code block #16.

Thus, using `GridBox`, we might be able to properly layout dropdown menus with their titles.

To create titles, we use [`widgets.HTML`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#HTML) - widgets with no values but plain descriptions. Combining these two concepts, we get:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive, GridBox, Layout, VBox

fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple','Lemon','Orange']
colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow']

header1 = widgets.HTML(description="Choose a fruit:", value="",)
header2 = widgets.HTML(description="Choose a color:", value="",)

drop1 = widgets.Dropdown(options=fruits, value='Banana', description='Fruit:', disabled=False)
drop2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=colors, value='Blue', description='Color:', disabled=False)

def update_dropdown(header1, header2, fruit, color):
    info = f"I would love to try a {color.lower()} {fruit.lower()}!"
    display(info)  

w = interactive(update_dropdown, header1=header1, fruit=drop1, header2=header2, color=drop2) 
controls = GridBox(children=[header1, drop1, header2, drop2],
        layout=Layout(
            grid_template_rows='auto auto auto auto',
            grid_template_areas='''
            "header1"
            "drop1"
            "header2"
            "drop2"
            ''')
       )
display(controls)
```

This realises dropdown menus with respective titles, but doesn't create a widget which is interactive, displays output and shows the entire title of a dropdown menu.

To do this, we use [ac24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8731272/ac24)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048425/7789963) for managing interactiveness and [aod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697581/aod)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/7789963) for displaying full titles. Finally, we have:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive, GridBox, Layout, VBox

fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple','Lemon','Orange']
colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow']
header1  = widgets.HTML(
    description="Choose a fruit:",
    value="",
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}
)
header2 = widgets.HTML(
    description="Choose a color:",
    value='',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}
)
drop1 = widgets.Dropdown(options=fruits, value='Banana', description='Fruit:', disabled=False)
drop2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=colors, value='Blue', description='Color:', disabled=False)

def update_dropdown(header1, header2, fruit, color):
    info = f"I would love to try a {color.lower()} {fruit.lower()}!"
    display(info)  

w = interactive(update_dropdown, header1=header1, fruit=drop1, header2=header2, color=drop2) 
controls = GridBox(children=[header1, drop1, header2, drop2],
        layout=Layout(
            grid_template_rows='auto auto auto auto',
            grid_template_areas='''
            "header1"
            "drop1"
            "header2"
            "drop2"
            ''')
       )
output = w.children[-1]
display(VBox([controls, output]))
```

This gives a widget that displays which colored fruit the user wants to try after user's first interaction with the widget:

[image]